# Is it possible to disable file indexing in a specific directory?

Tags: c#

I have a project with many many files (100k+) that I am processing.  I would like to save some CPU time by disabling directory indexing, but I need to do it programmatically because this application will be used by multiple people with varying technological skillsets.

I wasn't sure where to start with this, so hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'd start with the [Windows Search SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7388) and see if there's anything in there that might help you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Windows 7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out finally.

```
File.SetAttributes(Core.Main.pictureBox1.ImageLocation, FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx